# Javascript does not seem for fire at UAT website

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a  website in UAT. My ASP.NET webpage works fine in Dev environment.

But for same webpage ASP calender does not pop up, Radio button lists changed index event won't get fired. Basically no button post back to server either.

More info after spending several  hours trying to resolve this :

I removed the authentication part from my web.config file :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="30"
             defaultUrl="Survey.aspx" protection="All">        
      </forms>
    </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>  
  </system.web>
```

And now everything works. I am still stunned and have no clue why form authentication can cause this strange behavior.

I compared the IIS settings in both UAT and Dev and they seem to be identical.

Comment: I am using form authentication. User passes the login page but as soon as  gets to the Main page and clicks on any button he gets redirected back to login page. He needs then re-login but this time no events seemt= to work

Comment: To get help you will need to edit your question and provide a lot more details.  Include the actual code where possible.

Comment: One more thing i notice: If I try to go back to login page I get:401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I my case the form authorization was causing this.

I removed

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="30"
             defaultUrl="Survey.aspx" protection="All">        
      </forms>
    </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>  
  </system.web>
```

From web.config and problem was fixed.